# Why is wuauctl overloading my Win XP and how to stop it?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-update

Today I just opened my old laptop with Win XP (I use it every day, I don't shut it down nor hybernate, just close the lid in the evening and open in the morning) connected to Internet and it started using disk like crazy and slowing my system a lot. I noticed there is **wuauctl.exe** taking up to 200 MB in the RAM. [I noticed](http://www.runscanner.net/lib/wuauclt.exe.html) that it is a process that is to update Windows. *But since april 2014 Windows updates are no longer released from Microsoft!*

So why is wuauctl overloading my system and how to prevent it from doing that again?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft cannot just turn off Windows Update outright; they still host the *old* updates for at least a few years.

Also, Windows XP as in the core operating system doesn't receive updates anymore, but various components (e.g. Office or Internet Explorer) still occasionally do.

So all existing XP systems *will* have the Windows Update client running and periodically checking for updates.

The resource usage, meanwhile, is simply caused by a bad algorithm that the client uses to detect superseded updates. As [reported by Ars Technica last year](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/12/exponential-algorithm-making-windows-xp-miserable-could-be-fixed/):

> Machines using Windows Update retrieve patch information from Microsoft's servers. That patch information contains information about each patch: what software it applies to (for example, systems that have been upgraded to Internet Explorer 7 or 8 don't need Internet Explorer 6 patches), what knowledge base article it relates to, and, critically, what historic patch or patches the current patch supersedes.
>
> Windows patches are mostly cumulative. On a fresh install of Windows XP, you don't need to install all of the dozens of Internet Explorer 6 patches sequentially; you can generally just install the latest patch, and it will include all the historic fixes because it supersedes the historic patches that introduced those fixes.
>
> **Unfortunately, the Windows Update client components used an algorithm with exponential scaling when processing these lists. Each additional superseded patch would double the time taken to process the list.** With the operating system now very old, those lists have grown long, sometimes to 40 or more items.

That said, since XP is unlikely to actually receive any important updates, you might as well set it to stop checking automatically, in Control Panel (sysdm.cpl).

Comment: Microsoft also released an update that fixes this problem. It sounds like the author does not have that update installed.  Which causes a problem for fresh Windows XP installations which is part of the reason people suggest not using it.

Comment: @Ramhound: They did, but the same article also mentions that it turned out to be ineffective in actual systems, only working in MS labs...